# Powershell: Get-ChildItem, get latest file of files with similar names

Tags: powershell

I got a script to get files from a folder that I then put in a HTML-Table and mail.
In the folder you have files like `HR May 2020`, `HR April 2020`, `RR May 2021` etc.

Below is the code itself as a sample, this looks for other files but they come every month as well. In total I will filter 8 files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Temp\Test | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^RR_Prognos.*|^AllokeringBogNycklar.*' } | 
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
    Select-Object LastWriteTime,FullName
```

Now I am only interested in seeing the latest file of each, so using last or -days, month, hours or similar wont work.

I tried to find a better solution googling it but could not come up with anything that solved the problem.

So I just need to add to the code it it picks the lastest of each file i filter on, the filter is so it does not care about the month in the name.

Edit: Lets say I would use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\tm1 | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^RR_Prognos.*|^AllokeringBogNycklar.*|^Aktivversion.*|^AllokeringNycklar.*|^HR_prognos.*|^KostnaderDK.*|KostnaderProdukt_prognos.*|^Parametrar_prognos.*|ProduktNyckel_prognos apr.*' } | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-First 8 | Select-Object LastWriteTime,FullName
```

Then if one file does not come with the batch, it would show the 2nd last one of that as well. Is there a easier way to block that from happening?

Comment: Are the files are unique by the start of the file name? If so you can do something like `GCI D:\Temp\Test | Group {$_.Name.Substring(0,6)} |%{$_.Group|Sort LastWriteTime|Select -Last 1}` So it groups them by the first 6 characters of the file name, sorts each group, and grabs the most recent file for each group.

Comment: No filename is as long as the other, I was in on the Select -last 1 track for a while but realized that won't work.

Comment: file names don't have to be the same length. Can you logically group the files by using the first X characters of each file? Or, do you have a RegEx match like in your example for each one? you could group with that using `|Group {$_.Name -replace '(RR_Prognos|AllokeringBogNycklar).*','$1'}`. The key to use `-last 1` with my example is the grouping, then getting the last 1 of each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that you've provided the whole list that you filter against I can write up a real answer. Here we'll group by file name, then sort each group and grab the last one from each group:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\tm1 | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^RR_Prognos.*|^AllokeringBogNycklar.*|^Aktivversion.*|^AllokeringNycklar.*|^HR_prognos.*|^KostnaderDK.*|KostnaderProdukt_prognos.*|^Parametrar_prognos.*|ProduktNyckel_prognos apr.*' } | 
    Group {$_.Name -replace '.*?(^RR_Prognos|^AllokeringBogNycklar|^Aktivversion|^AllokeringNycklar|^HR_prognos|^KostnaderDK|KostnaderProdukt_prognos|^Parametrar_prognos|ProduktNyckel_prognos apr).*','$1'} | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group |
            Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
            Select -First 1
    } | 
    Select-Object LastWriteTime,FullName
```

Comment: Thx, I will try that in a hour when I'm connected to work again.

Comment: Works like a charm! TheMadTechnician, thank you. You tought me something I will have use for again for sure!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.  This iterates over each search string where you need the newest file.

```
$searchStrings = @('^pattern1*', '^pattern2*', '^pattern3*')
foreach($searchString in $searchStrings) {
        $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder |  Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$searchString" } | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending
        $newestItem = $items[0]
        Write-Host "newest item for '$searchString' is $newestItem"
}
```

Comment: I get the point, but that wont do it unless I missunderstand the purpose of your suggestion. It has to list the last one of each one of the 8 different names. This would split into to and just mention RR as the latest for example.